# Alexa Skill using S3 Select data

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, dom-events, es6-promise, alexa-skills-kit

I have a JSON object in my S3 bucket and I want to query this JSON data using S3 select, retrieve the needed fields and then concatenate the results into a string and return it back to some other function where Alexa will speak out this string.

My JSON data in the S3 bucket looks like this.

```
{
    person = [
    {
            "Id": "valid",
            "Name": "Anshu",
            "Address": "Templestowe",
            "Car": "Jeep"
    },
    {
            "Id": "valid",
            "Name": "Ben Mostafa",
            "Address": "Las Vegas",
            "Car": "Mustang"
    },
    {
                    "Id": "not valid",
                    "Name": "Rohan Wood",
                    "Address": "Wooddon",
                    "Car": "VW"
    },
    {
                    "Id": "not valid",
                    "Name": "John Cena",
                    "Address": "Wooddon",
                    "Car": "VW"
    },
    {
                    "Id": "valid",
                    "Name": "Ray Hope",
                    "Address": "Wooddon",
                    "Car": "VW"
    }
    ]
}
```

Now , I want to be able to query this data from my lambda function using S3 select.

I am using NODE JS for my Alexa skill.

I want names of all those people whose ID is "valid".

While Running the SQL query:

```
select s.name from s3object[*].person[*] s where s.name is not missing AND s.id = 'valid'
```

I get that data in the form:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Anshu"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ben Mostafa"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ray Hope"
    }
]
```

What I want to know is how do I accept the above result and then make a string as below using my lambda function?

```
str = "Anshu .Ben Mostafa. Ray Hope"
```

So, for the above query I want my result to be a string variable `str = "Anshu .Ben Mostafa. Ray Hope"`

I read about using promises to get back the result form the query here but I am not sure how to proceed further.

[link](https://medium.com/@thetrevorharmon/how-to-use-s3-select-to-query-json-in-node-js-5b2c5dca6dfc)

Also, I read the AWS documentation but I am unable to handle the results. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I could not find any great help using Node JS , I cannot use python because the rest of my code is in NodeJS. This is the furthest i have got so far  [link](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/68ddfc29-f407-48ec-979b-e94e57d3b3fc/query-amazon-s3-like-a-relational-database-to-provide-fresh-skill-content). But I do not understand how do I handle the result that is returned from the Query.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can store the result in the variable:

```
let result = [
    {
        "name": "Anshu"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ben Mostafa"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ray Hope"
    }
]

const str = result.map(r => r.name).join(". ").concat("."); // "Anshu. Ben Mostafa. Ray Hope."
```